# Trying to search a grid of characters in java for a specific word. How can I search from right to left after searching from left to right?

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

I have the following code to search a grid of characters below from left to right to find a word. This works perfectly.

```
// Left to Right
public static String findLeftToRight (char[][]board, String word) {
char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        boolean found = true;

        for (int k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
            if ((j+k >= board[i].length) || (letters[k] != board[i][j+k])) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" +j;
        }
     }
  } 
  return "String " + word + " not found";
} // end findLeftToRight
```

However, I cannot figure out how to search from right to left. Below is my attempt at searching from right to left, but it does not work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Right to Left
public static String findRightToLeft (char[][]board, String word) {
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

for (int i = board.length-1; i > -1; i--){
    for (int j = board[i].length-1; j > -1; j--) {
        boolean found = true;

        for (int k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
            if ((j+k <= board[i].length) || (letters[k] != board[i][j+k])) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" +j;
          }
        }
    }
    return "String " + word + " not found";
} // end findLeftToRight
```

Comment: I'd think a simpler approach would be to call the original method with the string reversed.  `new StringBuilder(x).reverse().toString()` should get you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((j+k <= board[i].length) || (letters[k] != board[i][j+k])) {
```

also needs to be reversed:

```
if ((j - k < 0) || (letters[k] != board[i][j-k])) {
```

Comment: Can you just explain to me why it is reversed/what it does? Thanks.

Comment: Your word is always letters[] in order 0-x. When you search right-to-left, then, (as you know) the second letter is to the left of the first letter, which means board[row][secondletter] compared to board[row][firstletter] is reversed. secondletter must be < firstletter (but it's still 0, 1 in order in letters). Just need to make sure you're checking all things in the right order.

Comment: You could, alternatively, reverse the check in letters, so you're checking does board[row][0] == (last letter index) and decrease the letters index as you move right. That would achieve the same result.